# Datagridview con filtros incluidos c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filtro, datagridview

Buen dia.
necesito ayuda sobre como hacer que en el datagridview aparezcan los filtros en cada columna, he visto varios programas que incluyen este tipo de filtros y otras opciones en el datagrid, pero no logro encontrar como hacer lo mismo. de antemano ¡muchas gracias[image: Quiero algo parecido a esto]

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9947/DataGrid-with-built-in-filter-functionality como referencia en este enlace te puedes descargar un código de ejemplo sin coste excepto que se tiene que crear un usuario sino tienes

Comment: Te lo agradezco, lo revisare.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.